# How to fix Haskell rigid type variable error?

Tags: haskell

I've the following code that determines whether two graphs are isomorphic using the [Weisfeiler-Lehman isomorphism test](https://davidbieber.com/post/2019-05-10-weisfeiler-lehman-isomorphism-test/). I understand there's no known polynomial time algorithm for conclusively determining whether two graphs are isomorphic, but for the purposes of this exercise, that is beside the point.

```
iso :: (Ord a, Ord b, Hashable a, Hashable b) => [a] -> [(a, a)] -> [b] -> [(b, b)] -> Bool
iso v1 e1 v2 e2 = m == n && go 0 Map.empty Map.empty [] []
  where
    ug1 = Map.unionWith (++) (Map.fromList $ map (, []) v1) (buildUG e1)
    ug2 = Map.unionWith (++) (Map.fromList $ map (, []) v2) (buildUG e2)
    m = length v1
    n = length v2

    -- Find old label.
    oldLabel = flip (Map.findWithDefault 1)
    -- Given the neighbors and old labels, compute new label.
    label l = H.hash . L.sort . map (oldLabel l)
    canonical = L.sortBy (compare `F.on` fst) . map (head &&& length) . L.group
    
    go :: forall a b. Int -> Map a Int -> Map b Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)] -> Bool
    go i l1 l2 c1 c2
      | i > n = False
      | otherwise = do
        let xs = map (label l1 . neighbors ug1) v1
        let l1' = Map.fromList $ zip v1 xs
        let ys =  map (label l2 . neighbors ug2) v2
        let l2' = Map.fromList $ zip v2 ys
        let c1' = canonical xs
        let c2' = canonical ys
        (c1 == c1' && c2 == c2') || (c1' == c2' && go (i + 1) l1' l2' c1' c2')
```

`Hashable` is from the package [hashable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable), and `buildUG` builds an undirected graph from a list of edges.

```
type Graph a = Map a [a]

type Edge a = (a, a)

-- Builds a directed graph.
buildG :: (Ord a) => [Edge a] -> Graph a
buildG = foldr merge Map.empty
  where
    -- insertWith called with key, f new_value old_value,
    -- and new_value is a singleton.
    merge (u, v) = Map.insertWith ((:) . head) u [v]

-- Reverses the edges.
reverseE :: [Edge a] -> [Edge a]
reverseE = map (\(u, v) -> (v, u))

-- Builds an undirected graph.
-- Since the graph may contain cycles, make sure
-- to not include the same vertex more than once.
buildUG :: (Ord a) => [Edge a] -> Graph a
buildUG edges = Map.unionWith ((L.nub .) . (++)) g g'
  where
    g = buildG edges
    g' = (buildG . reverseE) edges

neighbors :: (Ord a) => Graph a -> a -> [a]
neighbors = flip (Map.findWithDefault [])
```

The above is a minimum, reproducible example.

When the signature of the function `go` is omitted, then the problem is the following.

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘b’
  Expected: Int
            -> Map a Int -> Map b Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)] -> Bool
    Actual: Int
            -> Map a Int -> Map a Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)] -> Bool
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      iso :: forall a b.

...
```

Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005577/839733), if I explicitly specify `forall` and enable `ScopedTypeVariables`, there are new errors in the lines `let xs` and `let ys`, as:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a0’ with ‘a1’
  Expected: Map a0 Int
    Actual: Map a1 Int

• Couldn't match type ‘a0’ with ‘b1’
  Expected: Map a0 Int
    Actual: Map b1 Int

...
```

How do I fix this?

Edit:

Added imports on request.

```
import Data.Hashable (Hashable)
import qualified Data.List as L
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import qualified Data.Hashable as H
import qualified Data.Function as F
```

Comment: This is far from reproducible because of a ton on missing imports.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The imports are trivially resolved by an editor, and only serve to clutter the code, but I've added them anyway.

Comment: There are also F and H but anyway, I made it compile by giving an explicit type signatures for `oldLabel` and removing the one for `go`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thank you. I've since modified the code, but an explicit `forall` on `oldLabel` does compile. If you care to post an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. One question though: How did you know `oldLabel` needed a signature and not any other function?

Comment: "How did you know" I hate to admit it but it was trial and error. I thought it was `label` initially but that didn't help. So I cannot explain exactly why an explicit signature on `oldLabel` fixes things and how  Maybe someone more knowledgeable than myself will chime in?

Comment: As a thumb rule, whenever GHC gives a hard-to-understand error relating to a bunch of local definitions (e.g. using `let` or `where`), it is usually a good idea to add further type annotation to the local definitions. In that way, GHC often generates better error messages since they can now point closer to the actual issue. In this case, it looks like the Monomorphism Restriction was the issue, so adding a type annotation actually fixes the code.

Comment: @chi “_add further type annotation to the local definitions_” do you mean with or without explicit `forall`?

Comment: It depends. Usually, if you have `ScopedTypeVariables` on (which is a good idea), you need to add `forall a` if this `a` can be any type, completely unrelated to other types named `a` in the outer scope (perhaps it's best to rename the inner `a` as well in this case). If instead you need to refer to the `a` of the outer scope, then you need to avoid `forall a`. In your code, `oldLabel` must work on any type, not just on the outer `a`, so a `forall` is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.8.1/docs/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html#extension-ScopedTypeVariables), you can give everything type signatures, as follows:

1. Make `iso`'s type signature `forall a b. (Ord a, Ord b) => [a] -> [(a, a)] -> [b] -> [(b, b)] -> Bool`. The important change here is adding the explicit `forall`, to bring `a` and `b` into scope for later. (I also removed the redundant `Hashable a` and `Hashable b` since the only type you ever call `H.hash` on is `[Int]`, but this isn't relevant to the problem in your question.)
2. Make `go`'s type signature `Int -> Map a Int -> Map b Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)] -> Bool`, removing the `forall a b.` . Removing that means the `a` and `b` are the same ones that `iso`'s type signature brings into scope, rather than fresh ones, which were the source of your original errors.
3. Add these type signatures too, if you want:

```
oldLabel :: Ord k => Map.Map k Int -> k -> Int
label :: Ord k => Map.Map k Int -> [k] -> Int
canonical :: Ord t => [t] -> [(t, Int)]
```

Note that those last three functions are all called with `a` as the type sometimes and with `b` as the type other times, so they need to be polymorphic functions with fresh types. There were two ways to do this, either by picking new letters (which I did, `k` and `t`), or by using another explicit `forall`. If you instead used `a` or `b` without a `forall` for any of them, then it'd work for one call site but fail for the other.

One final note: you could have also chosen these two type signatures instead:

```
oldLabel :: (Ord k, Num v) => Map.Map k v -> k -> v
label :: (Ord k, Num v, Ord v, Hashable v) => Map.Map k v -> [k] -> Int
```

But since `v` is `Int` everywhere you call those functions in your code, and they're not exported, there's no need for that extra polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

I have determined by trial and error that giving an explicit type signature to `oldLabel` and not giving one to `go` makes the program compile:

```
  oldLabel ∷ (Ord a, Num c) => Map a c -> a -> c
  oldLabel = flip (Map.findWithDefault 1)
```

Disabling the dreaded monomorphism restriction also lets the program compile, but I'm somewhat at loss as to how exactly TDMR works in this specific case. In addition I don't know what explicit signature would work for `go`.

Comment: It looks like `go` can not have type `forall a b ...` since it needs to use the same `a` and `b` of the external definition. The DMR applies to `oldLabel` since it's not defined as a function: it's likely that eta-expanding to `oldLabel x = flip (...) x` also works (but is IMO worse than adding the right type annotation).

Comment: @chi Maybe ScopedTypeVariables can work here?

Comment: Yes. In that case your `oldLabel` should have type `forall a c ...` I guess.